# Which language to learn for starting Windows phone 8 development?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-8

I am currently a Web Developer / Designer. I am currently moving towards mobile development. Though I use and like Android I think Windows phone 8 has a really good future and would like to start developing for it.

I heard that it is possible to develop applications using HTML5, CSS and Javascript which was really exciting for me as it means I can get started really easily as I am really good in these. But I am a little doubtful whether it is really possible to access all the available features of the API using Javascript.

Will javascript based applications get really restricted like the current ones which run from the browser ? Or are they as powerful as the ones we are able to develop using .NET or Silverlight ?

Please remember that I am talking about developing for Mobile phones and Tablets based on Win 8 and not desktops.

Comment: Careful: Windows Phone 8 (which might come at the end of the year) is very different from Windows 8 (which is in public Beta right now).

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is already available on the other hand (7.1 or 7.5 depending on which version system you use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I am a little doubtful whether it is really possible to access all the available features of the API using Javascript. Will javascript based applications get really restricted like the current ones which run from the browser ? Or are they as powerful as the ones we are able to develop using .NET or Silverlight ?

With respect to Windows 8, JavaScript Metro apps get access to WinRT APIs, excepting XAML-related stuff (as you're supposed to be using HTML5/CSS3 for UI rather than XAML) and other APIs that duplicate functionality that is already standardized as part of HTML5. So, yes, they are as powerful.

No-one can tell you about any future version of Windows Phone, because there hasn't been any official information publicly released on that.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, there is no (final) information regarding which development languages Windows Phone 8 will support.

Windows Phone 7 supported development in Silverlight and XNA, so XAML is what we currently have.

Windows 8 uses XAML and HTML5 + CSS + Javascript for development; probably, Windows Phone 8 will support the same, but right now this is just speculation!

Comment: Windows 8 doesn't "use Silverlight" if you're referring to Metro, it uses WinRT.  Whilst WinRT may be similar, they're not the same thing!

Comment: Absolutely right, thank you for the correction @Ray!